# How to use GPS data with Maps SDK for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How to use GPS data with Maps SDK for Android? I'm looking at the documentation [here](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/index.html) for jetpack compose but is it possible to use gps with Maps SDK for Android?

```
val singapore = LatLng(35.66, 139.6)
                    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
                    }

                    GoogleMap(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxWidth(100f).height(200.dp),
                            cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState) {
                        Marker(position = LatLng((-34).toDouble(), (151).toDouble()), title = "Marker in Sydney")
                        Marker(position = LatLng(35.66, 139.6), title = "Marker in Tokyo")

                    }
```

I'm using this code to display my markers. How do I get the coordinates from the gps and dynamically create my marker?

Comment: It'd be much better if you'd post some code for the community can analyze and give you some helpful feedback.